# Can NEST 1.x work with ElasticSearch server 0.x?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

We've updated the NEST package to 1.6 for dependency-hell reasons but now most of our tests are failing. Our ES server is at 0.90 and we're not in a position to upgrade right now.

It looks as if NEST versions are tightly linked to ES versions and so 1.x of this package will not work with 0.x of ES, but I can't find any definite answers about this so I'm wondering if there's just a setting we need to change?

Comment: Does it help http://nest.azurewebsites.net/breaking-changes.html ?

Comment: Sorry, @Rob , that page doesn't give a definitive answer.